# getting data value from node, pointer confusion

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, nodes

So because of a circular dependency between my classes my Node looks like

```
struct Node{
    Word * data;
    Node * next;
};
```

So when creating a new Node I do (w being a Word type, newptr being a data member of the class)

```
newptr = new Node;
newptr-> data = &w;
newptr-> next = NULL;
```

If I want to access the data in the first node of a linked list, I think the correct method is

```
Word retVal;
Node *temp;
temp = head->next;
retVal = temp->data;
return retVal;
```

However data is a pointer to a Word type, it is not a Word type itself. But I want to return a Word, not a Word pointer. So would I do could I add `Word * word;` then `word = temp->data;` and `retVal = *word;`? My test program tells me something I did along the way is wrong because I'm getting a segmentation fault when I reach the function. I'm trying this

```
Word retVal;
Word * word;
Node *temp;
temp = head->next;
word = temp->data;
retVal = *word;
return retVal;
```

And using a cout line at various places I know my fault occurs at the `word = temp->data` line

My Word class members as requested:

```
class Word{
    public:
        char * charArray;
        char * sendBack; //ignore
        char * rest; //ignore
        bool isPigLatin;
        bool firstIsVowel;
        Word();
        Word(const Word& w);
        Word(char array[], int size);
        ~Word();
        void show(); //ignore
        //ignore everything below
        friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const Word& w);
        Sentence operator+ (Sentence s);
        Sentence operator+ (Word w);
        void operator+ (int i);
        Word& operator++(int);
        Word& operator++();
        Word& operator--(int);
        Word& operator--();
};
```

A lot of these things don't have to do with the linked list itself but I included everything just in case

Copy constructor for Word, as requested:

```
Word::Word(const Word& w){
    cout << "Copy constructor for Word" << endl;
    int size = 0;
    while(w.charArray[size]){
        size++;
    }
    charArray = new char[size + 1]; //+1 for \0 at end
    int i = 0;
    while(w.charArray[i]){
        charArray[i] = w.charArray[i];
        i++;
    }
    if(!w.isPigLatin){
        isPigLatin = false;
    }
    else{
        isPigLatin = true;
    }   
}
```

firstIsVowel, sendBack, and rest aren't declared until they need to be used in the ++ and -- overloads as they are for making a word into Pig Latin and back into English

my constructor:

```
    Word::Word(char array[], int size){
//In my test code I am hard coding a char array and its size, for the actual program I read in the char array from a file, then go thru the char array to get the size before calling Word(char c[], int s)
        cout << "Character Array Word constructor" << endl;
        int i = 0;
        charArray = new char[size];
        while(array[i]){
            charArray[i] = array[i];
            i++;
        }
        isPigLatin = false;
//this is needed for my Pig Latin function. All words will be read in as English, thus Piglatin = false. If the function to change PigLatin into English is called, nothing will happen since this is false. It gets set to true in the function that changes English to Pig Latin
    }
```

and default constructor

```
Word::Word(){
    cout << "Default constructor for Word" << endl;
    charArray = new char[1];
    sentBack = new char[1];
    rest = new char[1];

}
```

Comment: why are you allocating new Node when you make `temp` point to head instantly afterwards?

Comment: That's a good point. No reason for that to be in there. I was trying to take things step by step, there is no reason for that if I'm just setting it to `head`. This doesn't fix my segmentation fault however

Comment: @TommyK - `If I want to access the data in the first node of a linked list,`  Accessing data shouldn't involve any dynamic allocation whatsoever.  Just get to the node you want and return the data.

Comment: So you have constructed a circular dependency so you nodes are arranged in a little circle like this `head->a->b->c->a`(c points to a again)? the new node creating seems OK isolated seen, the code putting it into the circle isn't shown but nothing will work if that is broken. Now the access part is totally broken, did you really want to create a new node then turn it into a memory leak, then take the value and delete the node, totally breaking the circle?

Comment: @TommyK - Show us what `Word` is.  If it isn't safely copyable, then returning it by value isn't going to work until you make it safely copyable.

Comment: @Surt the dependency is between my classes. I have Word, Sentence, Paragraph, and Story. Sentence, Paragraph, and Story are linked lists that hold the object of the type before it (Sentence is LL of Word, etc). However my due to member functions, my Sentence class depends on Word.h and Paragraph.h (i.e overloading + to make Sentence + Sentence return a Paragraph), and my Paragraph depends on Story.h and Sentence.h

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie my Word class is large because it includes member functions to manipulate its data members. Basically Word is a character array (has to be char array, not string, specifically due to my assignment) that stores a word. I can post the whole Word class if you think it would help

Comment: It is common for `head` to BE the first node of the linked list. So if you want to access the data in the first node you probably want: `head->data` not `head->next->data`. You should of course check to make sure your pointers are not `nullptr` or `NULL` before trying to dereference them with `->` first though.

Comment: Your Segfault may very well be caused by `temp` being equal to `NULL` when you try to do `temp->data;`

Comment: @TommyK - Well simply put -- does your `Word` class have proper copy semantics?  If it doesn't then you can't return it, as you stated you wanted to do.  In other words `Word w1;  Word w2 = w1;` has to behave correctly (during the copy, when they both go out of scope etc.).  I'm assuming in that small sample that `w1` is populated with information (not just empty).

Comment: OK, do you want to delete the word after you have read it?

Comment: @YoungJohn I added a if(head!=NULL) and still get the same result. Also I populated the linked list before I called this in my test, so it shouldn't have been NULL anyways. and my head is a pointer to the first Node, not the first Node itself.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes it has a working copy constructor that I've tested before and checked, if that's what you are referring to

Comment: @TommyK - If the `Word` class just has a char array (an array, not a pointer), then there is no need to write your own copy constructor, as the default compiler version is adequate.  Now you've made it more concerning that you *did* write one if this is the case.

Comment: @TommyK - Let's see the copy constructor for Word.  You're also missing an assignment operator.  The reason I'm asking you for these functions is that you wanted to return a `Word` object, and to do that, you have to have all of these things coded correctly and without error.  The missing assignment operator is one glaring issue.  Yes, you have issues with the linked list implementation, but you need to focus on the copy issue also.

Comment: @Surt no, I just want to return a copy of the first Word

Comment: @TommyK - `Basically Word is a character array (has to be char array, not string, specifically due to my assignment)`  Your `Word` class contains pointers, not char arrays.  If it were `std::string`, then you would have no issues now.  I don't know why these teachers believe that using `std::string` takes away something from the learning process.  It definitely adds to the frustration process...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, maybe that is the lesson here!

Comment: @TommyK - Your copy constructor, sorry to tell you, is wrong.  It has undefined behavior.  You failed to copy all of your members from one object to the other, thus you have half-baked copies masquerading as full copies.  Those bugs are some of the hardest to find.  If the only pointer you need is `charArray`, then get rid of the other two pointers.  Also, why didn't you just use `strcpy()` and `strlen()`?

Comment: @TommyK - Can you also post your default constructor for `Word`?  I could give you what the code for the copying should look like in the answer, since I can't post it in the comments.

Comment: @TommyK - Please take a look at my answer.  I provided guidance on how to write the copy constructor.  Note that I am assuming you really don't need those two other pointer members.  Again, all of this wouldn't be necessary if you were allowed to use `std::string`.  Too bad.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie because my assignment specifically states: You may not use the C++ string class nor any C-style string manipulation functions. Do not even #include those libraries anywhere in your code. And I need the other two points for changing the Word into Pig Latin and back. All words will start off in English. So to change dog into ogday, I put 'd' in sendBack and 'og' in rest. Then I delete charArray and create a new charArray and fill it in the order of rest > sendBack > 'ay'. I need those 2 arrays for going back to English, because just looking at 'ogday' you'd have no idea how to

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie changing it back to 'dog' without knowing that 'd' and only 'd' needs to be sent back in front of 'og'. When going to Pig Latin you just stop once you hit a vowel then send the consonant sound back, with going back to English, you must know what part was send back since you can't simple check for the first vowel going backwards since you'd get 'gdo' instead of 'dog'

Comment: @TommyK - When you get requirements like that, my advice is to say "OK, I'll develop this library myself.  Thanks.".  So write your own strlen, strcpy, etc.  But overall, the requirements given to you are ridiculous to not even to use `strcpy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stated that you wanted to return a `Word` object.  Given that the object contains pointers to dynamically allocated memory, it needs to be copied correctly.

A correct copy means that the copy must be indistinguishable from the original object.  For your situation, this means that *all* the members from the source object need to be assigned to the destination object.  Your code failed to do that for two pointer members (`sendBack` and `rest`) and for one bool `firstIsVowel`.

Let's throw out the two pointer variables and assume `Word` doesn't have them.  The copy constructor would look something like this:

```
Word::Word(const Word& w) : isPigLatin(w.isPigLatin), firstIsVowel(w.firstIsVowel)
{
    int size = strlen(w.charArray);
    charArray = new char[size + 1]; 
    strcpy(charArray, w.charArray);
}
```

Note that I copied all the members directly from the passed in object.  No "business logic", no fooling around checking what the values were for those bools, nothing.  Just copied.  That is the job and only job of a copy constructor.

Second, you need an assignment operator.  The signature for the assignment operator is as follows:

```
Word& operator = (const Word& w);
```

In other words, you need to be able to assign a Word to another Word.  That can be written like this:

```
Word& Word::operator=(const Word& w)
{
    Word temp(w);
    std::swap(isPigLatin, temp.isPigLatin);
    std::swap(firstIsVowel, temp.firstIsVowel);
    std::swap(charArray, temp.charArray);
    return *this;
}
```

This uses the copy/swap idiom, described in many links on SO.  I won't go into it, but it does require that you have a working copy constructor and destructor for `Word` to implement it.  The `std::swap` is a utility function that swaps the two values.

So this should take care of the copying of `Word`, if we remove the extraneous two char pointers.  If they must be in there, then you need to amend the code above to correctly allocate and copy the data for those two pointers.

Comment: what does this line mean `Word::Word(const Word& w) : isPigLatin(w.isPigLatin), firstIsVowel(w.firstIsVowel)` ? I've never seen this before. I'm guessing this is copying, but how are you allowed to do this?

Comment: That syntax is how you initialize members.  It is the `member initialization list`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at what each line of code is doing on its own:

First, you are allocating a Node object on the heap and storing its address-value in a pointer-variable called 'temp'

```
temp = new Node;
```

Second, you are leaking that memory by overwriting its address-value, replacing that address-value with the one contained in the 'head' pointer-variable.

```
temp = head;
```

Thirdly, you're overwriting the address-value in 'temp' again by storing the address-of the second item in your linked list

```
temp = temp->next;
```

In fact, you could have replaced those 3 lines with the following:

```
temp = head->next;
```

Already, you have the potential for an error here, because there's no guarantee that `head` is not null, so you could improve the code by checking it against null.

Next, when you call `delete` on the `temp` variable, the second node in your list is released; leaving the first node in your list with a "dangling" (invalid) value for its `next` pointer.

However, since all you're after is the first node, (and assuming you want to delete the first node, not the second), chances are you probably wanted to do this instead:

```
Word* retVal = nullptr;

if (head != nullptr)
{
    // (1) Remember the address-of the first node for later deletion
    Node* temp = head;

    // (2) The second node becomes the new head
    head = head->next;

    // (3) Grab the data from the old head
    retVal = temp->data;

    // (4) Release the memory for the old head
    delete temp;
}

return retVal;
```

Comment: I think you mean `temp = head->next` in your last code. I have updated my code, but when I run it I still get the segmentation fault. Using print statements I know this is occuring at the `word = temp->data` line. I think it has something to do with me having to declare data as a pointer

Comment: @TommyK No, I didn't mean that at all - doing that would cause you to delete the second node in your list, and leave a "dangling" pointer (which is a likely cause for a Segfault).     The line `head = head->next` ensures that the first node is safely removed from your list before you delete it.

Comment: okay now I see. However, I am not trying to return a Word pointer, I need to return a Word.

Comment: @TommyK - `I need to return a Word.` Right, so you need to post the Word class members.  When you return a type, as my comment above stated, it has to have correct copy semantics.  For example, if you've got pointers as members and they point to dynamically allocated memory, then you better have coded a copy constructor, assignment operator, and destructor for `Word` that handles the deep copying issue.

Comment: @BenCottrell Actually I take back what I said. I am NOT deleting the first node, just returning a copy of it. Thus head should still point to it.